# How to use Tensorflow Federated on Windows?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, tensorflow-federated

I am trying to use Tensorflow's tutorial of doing image classification using Federated Learning over [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/federated/tutorials/federated_learning_for_image_classification)

Firstly, there were some pip dependency resolver errors popping up, but I installed the required libraries with the versions it asked for.

However, I am facing one of 2 issues:

- If I try to import `tensorflow_federated` , it gives the following error:

```
   263 
   264 def to_odict(struct: Struct,
--> 265              recursive: bool = False) -> collections.OrderedDict[str, Any]:
   266   """Returns `struct` as an `OrderedDict`, if possible.
   267 

TypeError: 'type' object is not subscriptable
```

- I found a forum suggesting to downgrade to tensorflow-federated==0.22. However, when I do that and run the import statement, it throws an error again because it's is implicitly importing a class which is no longer there in Keras (OptimizerV1).

I am really fond of Tensorflow's workflow. Is there any workaround of making it work on Windows?

PS: I tried it in both Google Colab and Jupyter Notebook.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`!pip install tensorflow-federated==0.20.0`

Comment: Same error. Tried this as well.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that error is symptomatic of an older python version. The latest version of TFF (0.27.0 at the time of writing) requires python 3.9. Currently, colab does not support 3.9. See https://github.com/tensorflow/federated/issues/2770 for context and some workarounds that allow you to use older TFF versions.